# ALFA AWUS036ACH Driver issues for Raspbian 11

Tags: wifi, kernel, driver

I have a driver problem, and I'll save you some time by describing it this way:

Computer: Raspberry Pi Zero 2w
OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Latest Update: Mon 24 April
(The update being: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`)

I am trying to install a driver for the ALFA AWUS036ACH Wifi Card.
I am following [this](https://store.rokland.com/pages/alfa-awus036ach-driver-install-help-raspberry-pi-os) guide
The guide states at one point:

> ***ARMv7 and below are 32-bit. AMRv8 introduces the 64-bit instruction set.***
>
> If your OS is 32bit use: ./ARM_RPI.sh
>
> If your OS is 64bit use: ./ARM64_RPI.sh

But `./ARM_RPI.sh` or `./ARM64_RPI.sh` don't exist, so I ignored it.

When I run `./install-driver`, I get:

> Your kernel header files aren't properly installed. Please consult
> your distro documentation or user support forums. Once the header
> files are properly installed, please run "sudo ./install-driver.sh"

I assume I need to run `sudo apt install -y raspberrypi-kernel-headers` to get my kernel header files properly installed but I just keep getting the same error over and over again.